# nano text file formatter?

Tags: c, nano

Is there a **SIMPLE way** to format nano file text?
My code is getting pretty messy, so it MAY help to format it.

Comment: I believe you're trying to remember `indent`

Comment: I adjusted the title on the assumption that you're looking to format C code (within nano), and not, say English prose or Fortran code.

Comment: Perhaps [this astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) was the artistic program you were thinking of?

Comment: Sometime second guessing the poster in not a good idea.You are forgiven, but to avoid more WRONG replies - can you delete the "for C code" even when nano is a text editor , not a C code editor in my case.

Comment: I was distracted, then, by your last sentence: "There is an app ... to format C code". Is formatting C code *not* your intention?

Comment: (also, you're free to further [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/465783/edit) or roll back my edits so that the post says what you're looking for)

Comment: So I did edit it.

Comment: Are you looking for something *within* nano to format it? What kind of code is it? I see Rui was also thrown off earlier and tagged `C`.

Comment: I am unable to answer this question because it is closed for "lacking detail". I think the question is pretty straightforward. And the answer is 'yes', nano includes support for formatting, as per [its manual](https://nano-editor.org/manual.html) (search for 'formatter' in that page). If a 'formatter' program is assigned in the relevant language's nanorc file, then pressing Alt-F within nano will invoke it. I think closing this question was inappropriate; I have flagged it for re-opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) command

Answer (score 2):

For formatting / "beautifying" C code, you have the packages in Debian, `astyle`, `bcpp` and `uncrustify`

For searching the packages:

```
$ apt-cache search beautifier | grep C
astyle - Source code indenter for C, C++, Objective-C, C#, and Java
bcpp - C(++) beautifier
bcpp-dbg - C(++) beautifier - debug
uncrustify - C, C++, C#, D, Java and Pawn source code beautifier
```